# MS Word Interop replacing fields in word document with data from database

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

Hi I have written some code to open a word document that contains fields e.g.«Date» and I am trying to replace the fields with data in the database. 
I am storing the Data in the database as variables then opening a word application and document then using an nested if statement with in a for each loop to find and replace each field in the document with the corresponding value.

Edit: The fields are all mergefields: { MERGEFIELD Fieldname }

I want to download the document afterwords or prompt the user to save on their machine.

Have i got this replacement thing right or is there a better way. 
thanks

```
 'Code to open the word template for invoices and editing it.
Protected Sub MakeDoc(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles InvoiceGenBtn.Click

    Dim ItmList = SQLHelper.RowQuery("SELECT  * FROM QoItemList WHERE Quote_ID = @Quote_ID",
                                     New SqlParameter("Quote_ID", Request.QueryString("QuoteID")))
    'Variables.
    Dim Qty = ItmList("Item_Quant")
    Dim IName = ItmList("Item_Name")
    Dim UPrice = ItmList("Item_QValue")
    Dim TPrice = ItmList("Quote_TCliCost")
    Dim Id = EditQuoteID.Text
    Dim Client As String = DdlClient.Text
    Dim Staff As String = DdlStaff.Text
    Dim Dates = RadSDate.SelectedDate
    Dim Total = SellValueTxt.Text

    Dim WordTemplate As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()

    Dim DocTemplate As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document()

    'Open and Store Doc Template.
    DocTemplate = WordTemplate.Documents.Add("~/WordTemplates/BlankQuote.doc")

    WordTemplate.Visible = True

    'Find and rewrite the document on fields.
    For Each Field As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field In DocTemplate.Fields
        If Field.Code.Text.Contains("Date") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(Dates)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("ID") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(Id)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("Staff") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(Staff)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("Client") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(Client)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("TValue") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(Total)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("QTY") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(Qty)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("IName") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(IName)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("UPrice") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(UPrice)
        ElseIf Field.Code.Text.Contains("TPrice") Then
            Field.Select()
            WordTemplate.Selection.TypeText(TPrice)
        End If
    Next
    'Download the File
    DocTemplate.Save()
    DocTemplate.Close()
    WordTemplate.Quit()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Mmmm. Do you have any say/input in how this document is constructed? There is definitely more efficient ways to go about writing data to a Word document... If not, do you have any information for us about *what kind* of fields these are? (Showing us a couple of field codes would do - I'm interested in the first word in the field code, primarily)

Comment: The field codes will all look like this {MERGEFIELD  Date\* MERGEFORMAT} in the document and no i don't have any say in how the document is constructed.

Comment: I had a similar requirement to yours and your code is very similar to what I had.  The other option is automating a mail merge but you get less control over the documents and the data for mail merge is 1 page for every 1 dataset row.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this. Using `Selection` is usually not efficient, even if the document is not visible and/or ScreenUpdating is set to false.

The following suggestion (snippet, only) works with a `Range` object. It sets the `Range` to the field at the beginning of the loop and also picks up the field's code in a String. Not calling `Field.Code.Text` multiple times is much more efficient. On finding a field, that field is deleted and the text is written to that Range (deleting the field does not invalidate the Range).

```
Dim rngField as Word.Range = Nothing
Dim sFieldCode as String
For Each Field As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field In DocTemplate.Fields
    rngField = Field.Result
    sFieldCode = Field.Code.Text
    If sFieldCode.Contains("Date") Then
        Field.Delete()
        rngField.Text = Dates
    ElseIf sFieldCode.Contains("ID") Then
        Field.Delete()
        rngField.Text = Dates
```